# Jinja, Generating Input Values, Based on Selector

Tags: python, jquery, jinja2

I want my input values to be populated upon selection in jinja.

Let's say I have a loop here for selectors:

```
       <label for="level">Choose a shirt:</label>

        <select>
            {% for shirt in shirtlist %}
                <option>{{ shirt.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

Upon selecting an item I want to populate other values like. `shirt.color, shirt.size` on the text input below it.

```
                <label for="color">Existing color:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="color" id="color"><br>
                <label for="size">Existing size:</label>
                <input type="text" name="size" id="size"><br>
```

I want to be able to put here those object values. I think this can be done with jQuery but I cant find a good source or if it can be done on Jinja.

Comment: You will need to do this with JavaScript, otherwise you'll need to pass query parameters to your page, and re-render each time e.g. `?shirt=abc`.

Check out the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) documentation, which also includes an example for `<select>`.

Comment: thanks for directing me what I should search!